# 'Authorize' only specific routes of a resource

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

There is this method `authorizeResource()` which applies specific policies to all routes (except the index route). Is there a way to apply policies only on specific routes, analogous to this function:

```
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController', ['only' => [
    'index', 'show'
]]);
```

Comment: I think you will need to use gates for this (protecting via middleware)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can realistically define middleware in the controller:

```
public PhotoController extends Controller {
    public function __construct() {
         $this->middleware("can:save,photo")->only(["save","edit"]);   //You get the idea
    }
}
```

This assumes you've written a proper policy (check https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization)

Comment: As I see this, the middleware will only pass if *both* save and photo pass. `authorizeResource()` however will map the correct policy to each route (e.g. `create()` to `create()` and `store()`), or am I wrong?

Comment: @Elwin actually `can:action,photo` will get a parameter named `$photo` from the action named `save` or `edit` (depending which one was called), it will then find the policy which applies to items of the type of `$photo` (e.g. `Photo` and apply a method called `action(User $user, Photo $photo)` from that policy.

Comment: @Elwin check https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7d116dc5a008e69c97f864af79ac46ab6a8d5895/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/Access/AuthorizesRequests.php#L82 : authorizeResource basically maps some route names to some actions like .e.g. the `edit` resource route to the `update` policy action. If you need a subset then you can probably just do them manually.

Comment: Ahh I see. I ended up doing a middleware for each route (5 in my case), since I only wanted to exclude the `show` route. It works, but I am not sure if this is the _cleanest_ way.

Do I see this correct, that a user _has_ to be authenticated so he can be authorized? Or is there a way to bypass authentication?

Comment: @Elwin yes, policies only apply to authenticated users. If not authenticated then an AuthorizationException is thrown by the Gate

Comment: Ahh bummer. There is no way to bypass this? (I keep seeing a _guest_ middleware but do not seem to find any documentation on that).
Otherwise I would stick with your solution.

Comment: @Elwin as far as I know there's no way to authorize guests in Laravel. Authorization is meant to be the next level above authentication.

Answer (score 12):

Despite pointed out by @JeffPucket in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47318008/1128918), the `only` option didn't work for me. I'm running **Laravel 5.5** and what did work was the inverse logic:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->authorizeResource(Photo::class, null, [
        'except' => [ 'index', 'show' ],
    ]);
}
```

Notice that you should pass to that option the actions (controller's methods) you **don't** want to apply your policy. In this case, `index` and `show` will bypass the authorization middleware.

Just for comparison, here are the results from `php artisan route:list` when using each option:

**only**

```
+--------+-----------+------------------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                    | Name            | Action                                         | Middleware                                       |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|        | POST      | comment                | comment.store   | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@store   | web,auth,can:create,App\Http\Controllers\Comment |
|        | GET|HEAD  | comment                | comment.index   | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@index   | web,auth,can:view,App\Http\Controllers\Comment   |
|        | GET|HEAD  | comment/create         | comment.create  | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@create  | web,auth,can:create,App\Http\Controllers\Comment |
|        | GET|HEAD  | comment/{comment}      | comment.show    | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@show    | web,auth,can:view,comment                        |
|        | PUT|PATCH | comment/{comment}      | comment.update  | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@update  | web,auth,can:update,comment                      |
|        | DELETE    | comment/{comment}      | comment.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@destroy | web,auth,can:delete,comment                      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | comment/{comment}/edit | comment.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@edit    | web,auth,can:update,comment                      |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

**except**

```
+--------+-----------+------------------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                    | Name            | Action                                         | Middleware                                       |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
|        | POST      | comment                | comment.store   | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@store   | web,auth,can:create,App\Http\Controllers\Comment |
|        | GET|HEAD  | comment                | comment.index   | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@index   | web,auth                                         |
|        | GET|HEAD  | comment/create         | comment.create  | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@create  | web,auth,can:create,App\Http\Controllers\Comment |
|        | GET|HEAD  | comment/{comment}      | comment.show    | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@show    | web,auth                                         |
|        | PUT|PATCH | comment/{comment}      | comment.update  | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@update  | web,auth,can:update,comment                      |
|        | DELETE    | comment/{comment}      | comment.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@destroy | web,auth,can:delete,comment                      |
|        | GET|HEAD  | comment/{comment}/edit | comment.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\CommentController@edit    | web,auth,can:update,comment                      |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+-----------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see above, the middleware is only applied to specific routes when using `except`.

Perhaps this is a bug in the framework. But it's hard to confirm that since this option doesn't seem to be documented. Even details on `authorizeResource()` method are non-existing.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [`authorizeResource` accepts an `$options` array as a third parameter](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a7cbe215cac1ae5c05923ee2da64cd6da734c571/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/Access/AuthorizesRequests.php#L83). Just pass `null` for the second argument and the syntax for options is the same as it is for route middleware.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->authorizeResource(Photo::class, null, [
        'only' => ['create', 'store'],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. I'm running Laravel 5.5